# hadoop fs -ls connects to wrong name node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I set up a Cloudera cluster with hdfs. In the name node, I am able to load data into the hdfs directory. The name node web ui checks out. I can see the replication across all my data nodes. However, when I ssh into a data node and do hadoop fs -ls /, I get a Connection refused, and I can see it is trying to connect to one of the data nodes, not to the name node. What kind of configuration error can cause that?

Comment: On the `datanode` check the value of `fs.defaultFS` in `/etc/haddop/conf/core-site.xml`. Verify that the value points to a valid namenode or nameservice. You might also need to deploy the client configuration from Cloudera Manager.